# Adjust video view on screen orientation changes android

Tags: android, video

I have a VideoView and am streaming mp4 files, which is working fine.  However I'm trying to set the video to centered on screen when in portrait, and set it to full screen when in landscape.  The code I am trying is below, but it is not working.  If I switch to landscape, it doesn't change anything until I switch back to portrait, then it's full screen and is too large for the portrait view of the phone.  How can I make my videoview adjust to full screen when in landscape, and switch back to standard centered in parent when in portrait?  I have added the configChanges="orientation" to my activity in the manifest.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();         
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 1);
        videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);          
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);          
    }
}
```

Also, I am under the impression that setting a 0,1 (false, true) after the layout param will either add the rule or remove it.  Is this correct?

thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the second parameter is the id of the view that the rule is relative to.  YOu need to use removeRule to remove it.

Truthfully I think its easier to just build a new LayoutParam object and replace the old one.  Also, you may need to call requestLayout on the parent after changing it, I'm unsure whether it automatically does it or not.

Comment: Okay spoke too soon.  When I am in portrait it displays perfectly, however if I switch to landscape the video disappears.  I can hear the sound but can not see picture.  Any thoughts?

Comment: For portrait changes I am doing... RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, R.id.videoView);      
      videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);
      videoView.requestLayout();

Comment: And landscape....RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, R.id.videoView);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, R.id.videoView);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, R.id.videoView);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, R.id.videoView);
      videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);      
      videoView.requestLayout();

Comment: just to clarify videoView is the ID of my VideoView, which is wrapped within a relative layout with id of videoViewParent

Comment: Your align to parent rules should be to videoViewParent, not to videoView as the second parameter.  That's the only thing that pops out immediately.

Comment: Switch the second param of the addRule method to point to R.id.videoPlayerParent, still no luck :(  Portrait works fine, but landscape still makes video picture disappear.

Comment: You're setting it to match_parent-  are you sure that the parent isn't being squeezed to 0 size by the rest of your layout?  Or if its set to wrap_content and you're set to fill_parent, the layout mechanism may decide that a size of 0 fits both parameters...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Gabe.  I have pasted my xml layout and videoplayer class to the following pastebin link...http://pastebin.com/kCziPewh     I really appreciate all your help!